# Password hashing produces different results every time in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, hash, laravel-4, passwords

I have problem with password hashing. This is my controller

```
 public function registerUser() {
    $valid = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'pass' => 'required|min:5',
        'pass2' => 'required|same:pass'
    ));

    if($valid->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('register')->withErrors($valid)->withInput();
    }
    // $password = Input::get('pass');
    if(Input::hasFile('photo')) {
        $img = Input::file('photo');
        if($img->isValid()) {
            echo Hash::make(Input::get('pass'));
        }else{
            return Redirect::route('register')->withInput()->with('errorimg','image-error');
        }
    }else{
        echo Hash::make(Input::get('pass'));
    }

    //return Redirect::route('register')->with('success','register-success');
}
```

Everytime I refresh my browser, the hashed pass is always change.

ex : if I put "qwerty" as pass, it should show

> $2y$10$PPgHGUmdHFl.fgF39.thDe7qbLxct5sZkJCH9mHNx1yivMTq8P/zi

Comment: Why do you think that is a problem? Doesn't Laravel have proper password hashing functions? If not use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: because everytime I input 'qwerty' as the pass, it always generate a different result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generating a different hash every time is on purpose, because the [Hash::make()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing) method will generate a random salt. A random salt is necessary to securely protect the user's passwords.

To check an entered password against the stored hash, you can use the method `Hash::check()`, it will extract the used salt from the hash-value and uses it to generate comparable hashes.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = Hash::make($password);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = Hash::check($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: I always fail with Auth::attempt(). And it works with your answer, using Hash::check()...
Thankss martin

Answer (score 1):

That's because if you don't give a `salt` `bcrypt` creates one every time it hashes something.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)